# If we have multiple indexes, row lock locks which index's leaf nodes?

Tags: mysql

Suppose we have a clustered index `ind_a` and a secondary index `ind_b`, when MySQL uses row lock, which index's B+ tree leaf nodes are locked? Are they both locked? If so, I guess the performance would be slow when many indexes exist.

If only one index's leaf nodes are locked (say `ind_a`), what if some other transaction locks `ind_b`, and violates transaction's atomicity principle? (e.g. two transactions concurrently updating same rows)

I think a reasonable approach is to first lock the index used in the SQL query, and then lock any secondary index whose keys will be affected, and then the clustered index. But this may cause deadlock, and it seems very complex.

Comment: What about doing the transactions inside of a Stored Procedure and use a Transaction and Commit to make sure the things you need get done the way you want them.  Or is there user input required so the lock happens while the user fills out a form or something?

Comment: @easleyfixed Concurrent update on the same rows may happen, and the SQL may access different indexes.

Comment: Set up a conflict where there will be a deadlock; run those queries; then do `SHOW ENGINE=INNODB STATUS;` and look for the second on "latest deadlock".